# How do I vertically middle-align on a responsive width/height container that gives the image max height or width

Tags: html, image, alignment

I am making a photography website, and when an image is clicked, it fullscreens the image (100% width and 90% height, there is a label on the bottom with 10% height) Here is an example of what I'm trying to do: https://www.schultzphoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/alaska-landscape-photography-001-northern-lights-reflection.jpg (Small-Screen the window and change the width/height) I have the image matching itself with either max height or width depending on the viewport dimensions correctly, and when it uses max height, the image IS horizontally aligned. However, when the image reaches the viewport's width, the image sticks to the top of the screen rather than vertically aligning

I've tried many of the simple vertical-aligns and tricks that use multiple containers and font-size and line-height, but none of them worked correctly with the responsive web design

HTML:

```
<div class="fullpicarea"> <!--Container-->
    <img src="../Images/Australia/Australia34.jpg" class="fullpic" id="Pic34"><!--Image-->
</div>


CSS:

.fullpic {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.fullpicarea {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh; /*Only 90 because there is a label for location of Image with 10vh*/
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 0;
}
```

The only result I've gotten have been the image sticking to the top of the container.